# Append SVG element in angular-nvd3 directive

Tags: angularjs, svg, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm using **angular-nvd3** directive for building line chart. In my case I have to create a custom background just like on the image. I've decided to realise it through adding new rect-elements to the nv-background tag in the chart callback function but it doesn't work with angular-nvd3 api nor with angular.element methods.

Has anybody faced the same problem? Maybe there is a more simple/elegant solution.

Here is the code i've tried.

```js
   vm.callback = function (scope, element) {

            var container = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("nv-background")[0]);
            var elem = angular.element("<rect width='1218' height='300' fill='pink'></rect>");

            container.append(elem);
            
            $compile(elem)(scope)
        };
```

```html
        <nvd3 options="vm.graph.options"
              data="vm.graph.data"
              api="api"
              on-ready="vm.callback">
        </nvd3>
```

[image: link to the example image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you [edit] to include a [mcve] showing what the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've updated the question with my code snipped